# Most efficient way to calculate complement of set A with respect to set B (vectors)?

Tags: c++, subset

I have a string vector containing all possible subsets of characters chosen from an n-length string (the subsets are stored as strings for the context of the greater problem, but there are no permutations of the same subset). I need to compare each such subset back to the original string and calculate its complementary subset of characters.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you give examples of input, expected output ?

Comment: Original string is entered as an argument, for ex. : "aadekmmnortww". Example subset of string characters could be "aanotw". Need to compare back to original string and calculate all characters not in that string, in this case "dekmmrw".

Answer (score 2):

Since your vectors are already sorted, [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) does exactly what you need.

```
std::vector<std::string> result;
std::set_difference(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
```

Comment: If they weren't sorted, the sort function is safe to use on strings as well as vectors, correct?

Comment: @aj1204 the `sort` function is safe on anything that provides random access iterators.

Answer (score 1):

It seems 'order' is the same so you may do

```
std::string compute_complement(const std::string& s, const std::string& sub)
{
    std::string res;
    auto it = sub.begin();

    for (auto c : s) {
        if (it != sub.end() && *it == c) {
            ++it;
        } else {
            res += c;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

else you have to order the `string` (with `std::sort`)